# How to make community made levels compatible with every game update, without re-cooking the levels?

Tags: unreal-4

Community made maps made in UE4 (BSP & simple assets), downloadable via Steam Workshop, is one of the main features of our hypothetical game. The maps should continue to be compatible regardless of game-updates, without re-cooking each map. **Is this possible?** Because now it seems every map has to be re-cooked after every game update. However, our hypothetical game can't work like that, considering it has to work with hundreds of community made maps which we can't expect users to re-cook every time.

Comment: What do you mean by "re-cooking" exactly? This affects possible answers a lot.

Comment: Well, the need for the author to open up his level in the editor and rebuild it again after there was an update to the game. It comes down to the following: community made levels should forever be compatible with any game update, without having to update the level in any way.

Comment: You need to outline the meaning of "any" game update as well. E.g. if you introduce brand new wall-climbing class, certainly level geometry should be re-evaluated.

Comment: Any update that doesn't require a re-evaluation of the level. Let's say there is a game called X, version 1.0, and users have created 100 levels. Then update 1.1 comes along; all the levels should still work (assuming there is no change in movement that requires all levels to be changed).

Sorry for lacking specifics. A friend and I are just brainstorming about a game and we want this possible problem addressed before we start anything.

Comment: Problem lies in defining a contract between the game and the levels. If game 1.1 changes the contract - all levels must be reevaluated. If the contract remains the same - no change is needed.